# Running Xcode 6 on 2009 iMac

Tags: macos, xcode, memory

I currently have Yosemite on my Early 2009 iMac. This iMac has a 2 GHz CPU and 2 GB of ram. However, whenever I try to run Xcode 6 on this Mac, it is slow-very slow. When monitoring my cpu, it hovers around at most 25% use when I'm running it. However, the RAM is using 1.99 GB out of 2.00 GB. My question is will my slow Xcode problem be solved by upgrading my iMac to 8GB of RAM?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the RAM is using 1.99GB? What tool are you using, and exactly how does it describe the usage?

Comment: I am reading what Activity Monitor is displaying.

Comment: Right, I was afraid of that. Ignore it. All modern operating systems use all the memory all the time -- anything that's not used for anything important is used for buffers and caches to speed up IO. Having said that, 2GB is not a lot, and you probably _are_ short of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of Xcode will increase if you increase the memory to 8GB. I am surprised that only Xcode is slow with 2GB. Xcode does take more memory than most applications

Comment: I increased my memory to 8GB but Xcode is still slow and Playground is unable to play at all.